# Serial debug output looking messy

Tags: serial, arduino-mega

I've got this quite basic code running on an Arduino Mega 2560, and the output is looking like I have the serial settings wrong, though I can't work out what to change.

```
void setup()  
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("test123");
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println("test" + millis());
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
ð¦·Z©÷
×ï¾üÿ7ß^|ïüûÿVÏuØëo~ìÿÓûzëýÿ{ßþ©×xñ×¤¿ïßûÏûýoÏ¿îãõI
õfwi÷`p¬½Ïª»QáÀª»¦·ð¦·Z©÷
test123
D



4ñjü¯÷~µÞMz¹Ý~¼
Ûþ}iû}ÒÖ­¦Ç¿÷ÿÂï½Õ¾;îö
```

I'm using the inbuilt "Serial Monitor" in the Arduino suite with settings 9600 baud and no line endings.

I see that the first println in `setup()` is sending the data as expected but all other comms are coming through as nonsense.

Any suggestions of what to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is unfortunately not valid in C++:

```
"test" + millis()
```

Rather than concatenating two strings, it's actually doing pointer arithmetic. It's taking the memory address where `"test"` is stored, and offsetting by the value retrieved from `millis()`. The result is a totally arbitrary memory location which gets treated like a string.

Generally speaking, it's arguably best to avoid string concatenation on Arduino anyway unless absolutely necessary. The reason is that it can use more memory than you might expect.

A simpler approach would simply be to do the serial output as a sequence of individual operations, e.g.:

```
Serial.print( "test" );
Serial.println( millis() );
```

Note the difference between `print()` and `println()`. The first one doesn't add a line break at the end, but the second one does.

Comment: Great, thank you. Can you also explain why string concatenation per http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringAdditionOperator isn't working how I expected it would in this instance, when one of their examples on the page is specifically `stringThree = stringOne + millis();`?

Comment: @bdx You can concatenate `String` objects like that because they overload the plus (+) operator. String literals in C/C++ (anything in double quotation marks `"like this"`) work differently. You can read more about the difference here: http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/String

Comment: I see. My assumption that a string literal would create a `String` object was false, it creates a null-terminated character array, and the `String` type also has an overload on the `=` operator to coerce a `char[]` to a `String`.

Comment: You can explicitly construct a `String` object by doing this: `String("test")`. It uses more memory than a string literal alone though, so it's important to be careful how you use it.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a minor addition to Peter's excellent answer and comments on concatenation and implicit typecasting with `String` objects:

Alternatives to construct the message (as a `char[]`) to be send might be:

1. use `sprintf()`

```
char buffer[80];  // for the complete output
char value[4];    // for millis(), which returns an unsigned long

sprintf(buffer, "I'm running for %u ms now", millis());
Serial.println(buffer);
```

*Note that `sprintf()` uses quite some memory!*

2. build the message 'manually':

```
 char buffer[80] = "I'm running for "; 

 itoa(millis(), value, 10);  
 strcat(buffer, value);
 strcat(buffer, " ms");
 Serial.println(buffer);
```